# How to render innerHTML of tag as nested HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

Using AngularJS I am making a GET request to receive a JSON document. From this JSON document, after some traversal, I find an array of additional JSON documents. With more JSON traversal on each object in that array, the resulting inner JSON documents are raw HTML.

I am trying to display each of those raw HTMLs in a page, however, I can only get them as a raw text equivalent which is displayed as mere text, not actually rendered in HTML.

Using $sce in my controller, I can render one specific path on one specific element of my array into HTML correctly but not all of them.

Here is my code:

```
//    controller:
$scope.latestEmails = function() {

$http.get('/emails/last/'+$scope.numberOfEmails).success(function(response) {
    $scope.insertHtmlHere = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.body[0].body[0].content);
        $scope.latestEmails = response.body;
    });

}

//    HTML
<div ng-bind-html="insertHtmlHere"></div> <!-- works for that one given element -->
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="email in latestEmails">{{email.body[0].content}} <!-- raw text displayed --></li>
        </ul>
```

The ng-bind-html correctly replaces the first object in my array's HTML. The ng-repeat part simply places blocks of HTML text (not rendered as HTML) in a list (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWpro.png).

Is there a way to render this HTML text received in my ng-repeat as full HTML? Is there a different AngularJS methodology I could use to accomplish this?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you do:

<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="email in latestEmails" ng-bind-html="email.body[0].content"></li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of loop and concatenation trickery I found my answer. Basically I loop through through the array of HTML documents, concatenate each one together and display that concatenated HTML.

Here is my solution code:

```
// Controller:
    $http.get('/emails/last/'+$scope.numberOfEmails).success(function(response) {
    console.log('made a latestEmails get request');
    console.log(response);

    // get HTML of each email and concatenate together
    var concat;
    for(var i=0; i<response.body.length; i++) {
        var email = response.body[i].body[0].content;
        concat+=email;
    }
    // display the concatenated emails as pure HTML
    $scope.insertHtmlHere = $sce.trustAsHtml(concat);
});

// HTML
<div ng-bind-html="insertHtmlHere"></div>
```

Hope that helps someone else who comes across this problem.